# Fullcalendar event contraints and resources

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am trying on [this demo in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/safofo) to have some events with scheduler and restrict to move some of them to specific resources.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    schedulerLicenseKey: "CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives",
    // put your options and callbacks here
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaDay',
    defaultDate: '2017-05-09',
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    editable: true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    fixedWeekCount: false,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    slotLabelFormat: "HH:mm",
    slotLabelInterval: "00:60:00",
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2017-05-09T16:00:00',
            end: '2017-05-09T17:00:00',
            resourceId: 'b',
            constraint: {
                resourceIds: ['c', 'd']
            }
        },
        {
            id: 999,
            title: 'Test Event',
            start: '2017-05-09T16:00:00',
            end: '2017-05-09T18:00:00',
            resourceId: 'a',
            constraint: {
                resourceIds: ['b', 'c', 'd']
            }
        }
    ],
    resources: [
        {id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A'},
        {id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B'},
        {id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C'},
        {id: 'd', title: 'Auditorium D'}
    ]
})
```

Now If you follow the instructions [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/resource_events/eventConstraint/) you will notice that inside the resourcesIds you specify the ids that you want the event NOT to go. But in the jsbin you can see that the reverse is happening.

Also if you switch on the month or week view you cannot drag and drop from one day to the other. Is restricting you due to the eventConstraint.

I am doing something wrong or is this something faulty?

---

Got around the problem with this solution for the moment but i think that the above is a bug. You can try [my solution here](http://jsbin.com/tojaxul).

What i did is to pass the constraints in a custom field on the event and to check on the drop if its correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now If you follow the instructions here you will notice that inside
>   the resourcesIds you specify the ids that you want the event NOT to
>   go.

No, the article says precisely the opposite of that:

> Additional properties can be applied to force an event to **stay within**
>   specific resources

(I added the bold.)

This means you give a list of the resources that the event can be dragged to. It cannot therefore be dragged to any resources not named within the constraint property.

As per the example given in the link you posted:

```
constraint: {
  resourceIds: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ] // constrain dragging to these
}
```

The event with this property will only be allowed to be dragged onto resources 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

I think you have mis-understood the documentation.

Comment: but again that is not explaining why you cannot drag the event on the week or month view, am i right?

Comment: that's because the week and month views are not Scheduler views (they are part of the basic fullCalendar) and therefore have no concept of resources. If you dragged an event there, how would the software know which resource to associate it with, let alone whether it was a permitted resource? If you want to use dragging and dropping of resource-aware events, you have to use one of the Scheduler views, either timeline (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeline/) or, an agenda/basic view enhanced with a resource list as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical_resource_view/getting_started/.

Comment: oh i see, now that makes sense. Thanks for the feedback. I will keep my solution for now that fits my needs but happy to know where the fault was.